# Does IFormFile.OpenReadStream() need to be disposed?

Tags: c#

Should `IFormFile.OpenReadStream()` be called inside a `using` block so it's properly disposed of?  Or will it be disposed of by the `IFormFile` after the http request finishes processing?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile.openreadstream?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_IFormFile_OpenReadStream

Comment: I've been using `IFormFile` objects for years and always wrap the stream in a using block. It is good practice to always dispose of streams you create. What is your concern about it? That it might get disposed of twice?

Comment: @Andy the thing is that you're not creating the stream, .net core created the stream.

Comment: @Luke -- the stream isn't created until you call `OpenReadStream`. Look at [the source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/033b1fb1cf681ea95d3954c08e4391c93cd72683/src/Http/Http/src/FormFile.cs#L81). Disposing of it is harmless to do, it returns a new `ReferenceReadStream`, resulting in a [no-op](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66799724/1204153). It is good practice to dispose of all streams you `Open...`.

Comment: That line you've pointed to isn't creating the stream, it's creating an object to contains the stream that already exists. I agree that calling dispose on that object does nothing. So what you're describing isn't calling `Close` on any stream.

Comment: @Luke -- I didn't say "Close", I said "Dispose". Those are two completely different operations. As a matter of fact, no one mentioned "Close", not even the OP. No idea what you are trying to say here.

Comment: On a stream Dispose calls Close() which is the only method that contains clean up logic. But that's beside the point, the ReferenceStream isn't responsible for creating or disposing of the IFormFile stream. That's the point I'm making. It already exists and we don't dispose of it by calling dispose.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The default implementation of `FormFile` creates a new `ReferenceReadStream` every time `OpenReadStream()` is called:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/033b1fb1cf681ea95d3954c08e4391c93cd72683/src/Http/Http/src/FormFile.cs#L81

`ReferenceReadStream` does not contain any unmanaged resources.  Calling `Dispose` on it is essentially a no-op.
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/033b1fb1cf681ea95d3954c08e4391c93cd72683/src/Http/Http/src/Internal/ReferenceReadStream.cs#L14

With that in mind, `IFormFile.OpenReadStream()` doesn't need to be disposed.  But disposing it also doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: I like this answer but like you said, "disposing doesn't hurt anything" so I'd recommend disposing it. No harm done and if the implementation gets changed on an update to use unmanaged resources then it's already covered and there won't be ugly memory leaks propping up

Answer (score 0):

`OpenReadStream()` does not create a new "stream"; however, it does create a new `ReferencedReadStream()`, where the base stream is reused. I would use `FlushAsync` as `Flush()` has no implementation, and then close the stream regardless.

```
return new ReferenceReadStream(_baseStream, _baseStreamOffset, Length);
```

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/033b1fb1cf681ea95d3954c08e4391c93cd72683/src/Http/Http/src/FormFile.cs#L81